# Getting "unable to resolve class" exception when importing application domain objects into a plugin in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I am working with the Grails Authentication plugin and trying to add a domain class from the plugin into my GORM. I am able to use plugin objects in my application when importing them with, "import com.grailsrocks.authentication.AuthenticationUser", but getting "unable to resolve class" exception when trying to access my application objects from the plugin (I am trying to use the domain class "User" and my import command is "import blap.User" - package name is blap). Both import commands work from the shell, and the import statement is not triggering an error in STS.

I am new to grails, so I'm probably doing something very wrong. But, at this point I am running out of ideas, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Vitaly

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used the Grails Authentication plugin before, I don't think you should be modifying the plugin classes. In general, you should extend the plugin class you want to modify in your application and use your application class instead.

Actually, from reading the docs, it looks like you should use the event handling to modify the plugin behavior.

From the [plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/authentication):

> The default AuthenticationUser domain class is minimal. If you want to change constraints or add fields (you may consider using a separate class instead for extra user data) you just redefine the onNewUserObject event and return your own instance of a domain class or similar wrapper around another authentication database such as LDAP